# How to pass value as prop from another file to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to pass a value from file A to a function in file B that changes with slider input. I am trying to do this by passing the value as a prop.

I am currently getting the error "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0." when I call GraphArrayFunction() in file B because I am not passing a prop through the function. How would I pass a prop through the function if I want the prop to be able to be changed?
File A:

```
const test = Number(rangeValue);
GraphArrayFunction({test});
```

File B:

```
interface MainProps {
    test: number
}

export const GraphArrayFunction = (props: MainProps) => {
    const {test} = props;
    let i = test 
    const j = 1;
    const graphArray = [];
    //let user change i
    if (i > 1) {
        while (j < i + 1){
            graphArray.push(randomNumber());
            j++;
        }
    }
    return graphArray;
}

const Graph = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <GraphOutline>
                {GraphArrayFunction().map((numbers, index) => 
                <HeightBars height={numbers} />)}
            </GraphOutline>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default Graph
```

Comment: I can see your GraphArrayFunction has no arguments being passed while calling

Comment: @AdeshKumar Yes, it has no arguments because I am not sure what to put the argument as. It works when I hardcode the value ({prop : 10})

Comment: if you dont want any argument simply remove props:MainProps from the function declaration

Comment: you are looping on i which is the props and your function is not getting that props as you are not passing it

Comment: @AdeshKumar How would I pass i as the prop when I call the function?

Comment: simply pass GraphArrayFunction({test:10})

Comment: what exactly your requirement is

Comment: @AdeshKumar I don't have an exact requirement though. It is supposed to be able to be changed with a range slider.

Comment: I have added one answer with comments. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

File A:

```
const test = Number(rangeValue);
// Here you are passing {test} as an argument of function so it will work here.
GraphArrayFunction({test});
```

File B:

```
interface MainProps {
    test: number
}

export const GraphArrayFunction = (props) => {
    const {test} = props;
    let i = test 
    const j = 1;
    const graphArray = [];
    //let user change i
    if (i > 1) {
        while (j < i + 1){
            graphArray.push(randomNumber());
            j++;
        }
    }
    return graphArray;
}

// Error you are getting from this Graph function as you are calling above function here as well

const Graph = () => {
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <GraphOutline>
// here you are not passing any argument. I have passes test:15 and your // function will use this. And that's why you are getting error that function // should have at least one argument 

                {GraphArrayFunction({test:15}).map((numbers, index) => 
                <HeightBars height={numbers} />)}
            </GraphOutline>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}

export default Graph
```